# Blender 2.8 extrude vertices

Tags: vertices, extrude

I apologise in advance if it's been answered before. I'm relatively new to blender and have been following this timelapse video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wRzYBsTvnXY). At around 7:37, it seems the creator can extrude the vertices along the x-axis (or in any axes).
[image]

However, when I tried it, Blender just wouldn't let me extrude like the video did even I pressed 'xyz' during the extrusion.
[image]
[image]

From what I'm seeing is, he first selected (Ctrl) two vertices then extruded (E) using the mouse. Am I missing something? Or do I have to do some custom settings? I'm aware that there're some major updates from 2.79b to 2.8 but this is not changed, right?

Comment: maybe deactivate the modifier clipping option?

Comment: Ok that works, thanks! Stupid me :x

Comment: Then please mark you question as answered, otherwise stackexchange will eventually bring back this question again and again until it is answered.
Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deactivate the Mirror modifier *Clipping* option to prevent vertices from sticking to mirror plane, then it's possible to move them away from it even if they are already placed on it.